# Java Large Object storage - Protocol buffers, MemoryMappedFiles

Tags: java, performance, jvm, protocol-buffers, memory-mapped-files

We have Java program with Large Objects of Tree structure, ArrayList and MultiMaps.

The problem I'm having is, we have allocated 3GB of heap memory but it is still running out of space.

I'm wondering if anyone here can suggest a way to store these objects outside heap and read the chunks of data back into java program on need basis for each processing call. I'm interested to store them in files and not database for other reasons.

I came across 'Memory Mapped File' and some one suggested "Protocol Buffers" on a related question, these are alien concepts to me at the moment, and wondering if there is an easy way. I also couldn't find good examples on both of these concepts.

Would really appreciate your help on this.

Performance is very important consideration and I'm aware of JVM heap allocations but I'm not looking for increasing JVM heap size.

Comment: Sounds like an *XY problem*. Think I'm wrong? Provide details about the "Large Objects" and how you need to use them. Show us why you want to explore exotic solutions like a mem mapped file.

Comment: I have put data in a memory-mapped file with Java, but the disadvantage is that data stored there are not Java objects-- it just looks like a big byte array.

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks for your response. We have backend table data we read into Java and based on some logic this data is turned into Java data structures - Tree data structures, ArrayList of Objects and MultiMaps.

I have Java logic that reads from these Objects and data structures and process user requests based on their inputs.

I'm really sorry if that is still not clear. Wish i can provide more details.

And there is no reason i have to go for exotic solutions. I would take any of your suggestions.

Comment: @antlersoft, Humans wouldn't read the file content. It would same Java program that would read the data.

Can you guide me where i can find more details and mainly examples ?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider storing data in something like [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map).  This uses off heap memory and can be stored and accessed without creating any garbage.  This allows you to reduce the heap size but you still need to buy a sensible about of memory.  I would suggest you consider having at least 32 GB of memory whether you use on heap or off heap for larger datasets.

> there is no reason i have to go for exotic solutions

In that case, stick to an on heap solution.  You can buy 16 GB of memory for around $200.

> I'm not looking for increasing JVM heap size.

Ask yourself how much time/money you are willing to invest to avoid increasing the heap.  You can certainly do this but to save 4 GB I wouldn't spend a day on this. To Save 40 GB or 400 GB or 4 TB that is a different story.

Comment: Hi Peter,

Thanks a lot for your response.

I will check your suggestion.

And, This is not for my personal work, i could have easy got the 16GB RAM. This is my office project and It's not easy to get that amount of memory, believe me.

Comment: @bluzeee Yes, some places will happily waste a lot of time/money to avoid spending money on hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Protocol Buffers does not work well with memory-mapped files, because the file contains the encoded data, which must first be decoded before you can use it. This decoding step generates heap objects. You might be able to use Protobufs with memory-mapped files if you split the file into lots of small messages which you decode on-demand when you need them, but then immediately discard the decoded versions. But, you may waste a lot of time repeatedly decoding the same data if you aren't careful.

[Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org) is a newer format that is very similar to Protocol Buffers but is explicitly designed to work with memory-mapped files. The on-disk format is designed such that it can be used in-place without a decoding step. We are working on a [Java version](https://github.com/dwrensha/capnproto-java/) which should be ready for production use within a few weeks.

(Disclosure: I'm the creator of Cap'n Proto, and also was previously the maintainer of Protocol Buffers at Google.)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use immutable collections from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained), they're usually less memory hungry.

You may be able to use `String.intern` if strings take a fair portion of your memory.

You may save a lot using [trove4j](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) if you have a lot of boxed primitives.

You may do some small tricks like using smaller datatypes, etc....

*But your really should make your office get more memory before wasting your time with computers having as much RAM as a smartphone!*

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I have checked Trove and HPPC but i have objects and not primitives. I have also checked Huge Collections and based on what i checked, i need custom interfaces but i'm using arraylists and map of Collection Objects (not strings alone) which are major consumers of memory.

I have finally settled onto Fastutil but didn't see any memory savings, not sure if i'm doing something wrong. I have to check further.